# How to update Office 2010 on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, updates, microsoft-office-2010

I don't think Windows 8.1 has `Microsoft Update` that can be used to update Office 2010.

Can I update Office 2010 on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 2010 is updated through Windows Updates. In Windows 8.1 it is the same thing. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and write `Update` and click on Check for Updates. If there are any updates or patches for Office 2010 you will download them through Windows Update.